# Exception Handling for incomplete parameters in Ant build

Tags: java, ant

Correct one: `ant verifyParameters -DrestoreValue=false`

Ex: `ant verifyParameters -Drestoreval=false`

I wanted to throw an error if the parameter spelled wrongly, even if I pass multiple parameters it should catch for all of them and throw an error.

Comment: Sure, Thanks Andy. Changed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to check all wrongly spelled parameter names, because each one is a valid parameter on its own. There are too many possibilities to spell it wrong.

But you can check, wether the right parameter is set and fail if it's missing.

Here is an example. The main target `default` is shielded by the dependend target `check-parameter` which fails, if parameter `restoreValue` is not set.

```
<project name="option-test" default="default">

  <!--
    This is the main target. It depends on target check-parameter which fails,
    if parameter restoreValue is not set.
  -->
  <target name="default" depends="check-parameter">
    <echo message="Start build ..." />
    <echo message="restoreValue = ${restoreValue}" />
  </target>

  <!--
    This helper target sets property parameterok to true, if restoreValue is set.
    And to false, otherwise.
  -->
  <target name="check-is-set">
    <condition property="parameterok">
      <isset property="restoreValue"/>
    </condition>
  </target>

  <!--
    This target depends on target check-is-set, which calculates the parameterok property.
    The unless attribute evaluates the parameterok property, so that the target body
    is only excuted, if paramterok=false.
    So the build fails only if parameter restoreValue is not set.
  -->
  <target name="check-parameter" unless="${parameterok}" depends="check-is-set">
    <fail message="Parameter restoreValue not set!" />
  </target>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: but these parameters are not mandatory, they can skip some of them and run the target.

Comment: Basically, Validation is required for the parameters which has passed to that target.

Comment: There are a lot of predefined properties in Ant and you cannot distinguish between the predefined, the properties set via -D parameter or -propertyfile parameter or otherwise defined properties. There is a predefined property `sun.java.command` which holds the command line including the -D parameters. But there is no way to parse and handle the parametes in Ant. Maybe you can handle this via a Groovy task.

Comment: Another alternative is to call Ant indirectly via a batch file or shell script. So you can check the parameters beforehand via scripting.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible, but it's a bit hacky and not really a feature of Ant.

Ant has access to the user's invoked command in the property `sun.java.command`. With a bit if regex work, it is possible to create a condition that validates the command as you require:

```
<fail>
    <condition>
        <or>
            <not>
                <matches
                    string="${sun.java.command}"
                    pattern=" -DrestoreValue[ =]"
                />
            </not>
            <matches
                string="${sun.java.command}"
                pattern=" -D.+ -D"
            />
        </or>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

This should work if you simply put it anywhere in your Ant script, outside of a target, assuming you want this check to run every time. If you only want it to run for certain targets, I recommend creating a new target containing only this conditional failure, and make the relevant targets depend on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the above code which you suggested and ran the target but every time even though if i pass correct parameter its failing. Please let me know if i am missing some thing here.

Comment: <target name = "verifyParameters" depends = "verify">
   <echo message="restoreValue--- ${restoreValue}"/>
  </target>

  <target name = "verify">
  <fail>
      <condition>
          <or>
              <not>
                  <matches
                      string="${sun.java.command}"
                      pattern=" -DrestoreValue "
                  />
              </not>
              <matches
                  string="${sun.java.command}"
                  pattern=" -D.+ -D"
              />
          </or>
      </condition>
  </fail>
  </target>

Comment: bash-4.1$ ant verifyParameters -DrestoreGraph=false
Buildfile: build.xml

verify:

BUILD FAILED
/scratch/m/build.xml:702: condition satisfied

Total time: 12 seconds

Comment: Try using `<echo>` to check the value of `${sun.java.command}` so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: ant verifyParameters -DrestoreValue=false
Buildfile: build.xml

verify:
     [echo] sun.java.command is org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp  verifyParameters -DrestoreValue=false

BUILD FAILED
build.xml:704: condition satisfied

Total time: 11 seconds

Comment: This is the value i got:

Comment: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp verifyParameters -DrestoreValue=false

Comment: Edited my answer. For some reason your command is keeping the `=` in between the property names and values, while on my machine it replaces them with a space.